# Prove by the precise definition that if $\lim_{x→a} f(x) = ∞$, then $\lim_{x→a} (−f(x)) = −∞$.

Tags: calculus, epsilon-delta

> Prove by the precise definition that if $\lim_{x→a} f(x) = ∞$, then
>    $\lim_{x→a}  (−f(x)) = −∞$.

Let $M>0$, since $\lim_{x→a} f(x) = ∞$, there exists $δ>0$ such that
$$ 0<|x-a|<δ\implies f(x)>M $$

This is what i know, but how do i then prove that the change to $-f(x)$ results in a $−∞$ limit.

Thanks.

Comment: So it is $-f(x) < -M$

Comment: ... from which we can say that $-f(x)\lt -M=G\textrm{ (say)}$ for all $G\lt 0$ when $0\lt |x-a|\lt\delta$. Can you conclude?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that for every $m<0$, there exists some $\delta$ such that if $$0<|x-a|<\delta\implies -f(x)<m$$

To do that, here's a simple **hint**:

What happens to the inequality $-f(x)<m$ if I multiply it by $-1$?